# VS Code Debugger - Felix Becker - Debugger doesn't hit anything

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I have recently installed php debugger by Felix Becker.
No matter whatever config settings I do, my debugger is not hitting anything.
Following are my conf files.

**xdebug.ini**

```
[xdebug]
; debug
xdebug.default_enable = $value
xdebug.remote_autostart = $value
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.remote_host = $value
xdebug.remote_port = $value
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.idekey = $value

; profiling
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /tmp

zend_extension=xdebug.so
```

**Launch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9009,
            "pathMappings": {
                "path/path": "$value"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
  
            "port": 9009,
            "pathMappings": {
                "path/path": "$value"
            }
        }
    ]
  }
```

Am I missing anything here ?

Comment: What's your PHP and Xdebug versions?

Comment: PHP 7.3.11
php debug by Felix Becker v1.13.0

Comment: Thanks, but I've asked about Xdebug version (the actual PHP extension that does debugging on PHP side) and not VSCode extension. I'm asking because Xdebug v3 uses different config params than v2 -- maybe it's the case here as well.

Comment: Xdebug v3.0.1, by Derick Rethans

Comment: *"Xdebug v3.0.1, by Derick Rethans"* In such case please go through https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide and update your Xdebug config. You are using Xdebug v2 config params, v3 uses DIFFERENT config params. Your current settings, almost all of them do nothing in v3.

Comment: it worked... yayyy.. thanks much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Xdebug v3.0.1, by Derick Rethans

You are using Xdebug v3 but keep using Xdebug v2 config parameters. You need to go through [Upgrading from Xdebug 2 to 3 Guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide) and adjust your settings (mostly just change the parameter name).

Xdebug v3 uses **different** config params than Xdebug v2. From what I see 8 out of 9 "xdebug." params from your current php.ini do **nothing** in Xdebug v3.

For Xdebug 3 it should be something like this (based on your original config):

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so

[xdebug]
xdebug.mode = debug
; for profiling switch to below:
;xdebug.mode = profile

xdebug.client_host = ${PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST}
xdebug.client_port = ${PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_PORT}
xdebug.discover_client_host = false
xdebug.start_with_request = ${PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_AUTOSTART}
xdebug.idekey = ${PHP_XDEBUG_IDE_KEY}
xdebug.output_dir = /tmp
```

P.S. `xdebug.discover_client_host` will now fallback to `xdebug.client_host` on failure (unlike v2 that would try autodetected host only).

P.P.S. `xdebug.default_enable = 1` is replaced by `xdebug.mode = develop`. If you need that then you can list multiple values via comma, e.g. `xdebug.mode = develop,debug`

Answer (score 0):

A fix for Becker extension was pushed in v1.52.1, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is:issue+milestone:%22November+2020+Recovery%22+is:closed

---

The php debugger extension by Felix Becker is using previously-deprecated api and so the last vscode version 1.52 means it won't hit breakpoints.  There are many issues on vscode's github on this.  A vscode team member suggests enabling this setting to fix:

`Debug: Allow Breakpoints Everywhere`

see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112288#issuecomment-743456329

The other option is to use a different extension which has updated its code to accommodate the deprecations.  For examples, see https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug/issues/424#issuecomment-727932756

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried new plugin by tiansin. It is still the same. no luck.

Comment: Did you try the setting too?

Comment: Yes Mark. Tried both the things. it doesn't hit any of the breakpoints.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I'll leave the answer here because it caused a lot of grief for people who might find this question.