# Why not working breakpoint in PHP VSCode?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

1. Install XAMPP v3.2.4 x64 in `c:\xampp` and set path to environment variable

[image: XAMPP]

[image: environment]

2. Get all text in `phpinfo()` and download dll file as per https://xdebug.org/wizard and copy in `c:\xampp\php\ext`
   and add text `zend_extension=path` in end of `php.ini` and check `phpinfo()` page and xdebug adding to this

[image: Xdebug]

3. Add `[XDebug] xdebug.remote_enable = 1 xdebug.remote_autostart = 1`
   in php.ini

[image: php.ini]

4. Install VSCode v1.52.1

[image: VSCode]

5. install Php Debug v1.13.1

[image: PHP debug]

6. Create project in `htdocs` name of test and create file in to `test.php`

[image: project]

7. Text in to `test.php` and set breakpoint in line
8. Create automatic `launch.json` for PHP

[image: launch.json]

9. Start debug
10. Start chrome and url: `localhost/test/test.php`

But when refresh page breakpoint not working and not stop code.

Comment: You are using Xdebug v3 .. but still trying to use config params for v2. They will NOT work. Please check https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide. Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65350070/783119 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141934/783119

Answer (score 0):

just just check listen port

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.1-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9000
```

Comment: You DO NOT NEED these 2 lines for Xdebug v3: `xdebug.remote_enable = 1` and `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1`. Xdebug 3 will complain about them in your error log when it sees old v2 values. It may happen for every PHP script that it executes so your error log may be flooded with unnecessary entries.

Answer (score 0):

I Faced this problem and finally solved it by these steps.

1. First check VSCode is able to receive Xdebug Message via **log=true**
2. Second and most important one is related to **pathMappings** which is map remote code to your local code 
   hear is my VSCode debug configuration

   ```
       "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
       "type": "php",
       "request": "launch",
       "port": 9001,
       "log": true,
       "pathMappings": { "/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}"
   ```
3. Finally configure your xdebug.ini (you can also put them in php.ini  )

   ```
    zend_extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.1-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll 
    xdebug.remote_enable=1
    xdebug.remote_autostart=1
    xdebug.remote_port=9001
    # Very Import !! remote_connect_back should be turned off
    xdebug.remote_connect_back= 0
    xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.X
    xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
   ```

(these configurations are related to xdebug 2.9.X  )